# I'm trying to add a click event, using javascript, to each column of a barchart in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, chartjs-2.6.0

I've been trying to add a click event to each column in a bar chart using Chart.js.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to make a click event on each column execute the code I want.

The goal for this is when a user clicks on a particular bar of the chart, it executes a php form submit that takes them to another page on the website.

The bar chart data is populated from an SQL database via php when the user goes to the page.

Here's an example of the code I have so far ...

```
<canvas id="briskChart" style="margin:auto;display:block;background-color:white;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;padding:10px;"></canvas>

<script>
var red = <?=json_encode($count1[0]);?>;
var yellow = <?=json_encode($count2[0]);?>;
var green = <?=json_encode($count3[0]);?>;
var blue = <?=json_encode($count4[0]);?>;
var grey = <?=json_encode($count5[0]);?>;

var dept = <?=json_encode($row['dept']);?>;


var c1 = document.getElementById('briskChart')
var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");
var briskChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Watch', 'Retired'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [red, yellow, green, blue, grey],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)',
                'rgba(255, 216, 0, 0.4)',
                'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4)',
                'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.4)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 216, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(160, 160, 160, 1)'

            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]

    },
    options: {
    onClick: event => {
        document.bred.submit();
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            fontSize: 24,
            text: dept + ' Dept Risk Summary',
            fontColor: '#000000'
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        gridLines: {color: '#000000'},
                        ticks: {
                            fontColor: "black",
                            fontSize: 16
                            }
                        }],
                yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        gridLines: {color: '#000000'},
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            fontColor: "black",
                            fontSize: 16,
                            stepSize: 1
                            }
                        }],
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

Here is the html:

```
<form action='../php/bred.php' method='POST' name='bred'>
</form>
```

The documentation for Chart.js is very limited regarding click events.  For each data series, when the column is clicked on, I want to run a corresponding `document.[form name].submit` to take the user to that new page.

If anybody has any experience doing this with Chart.js and could point me in the right direction, I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried so far. If you haven't tried anything, please try something. Start here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html

Comment: Updated the post.  I've tried using the 'onClick' functionality, but unfortunately that applies to the whole chart.  I need to be able to click on each bar, and have it take you to a different page based on that data.  I think Chart.js is almost there since it will display a popup bubble of the data when you hover (or some other event as defined in the docs).  What I need is something where more than just a popup showing the value, or an alert can be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `click` handler that retrieves the `x` and `y` values from the chart. Then, using that data, you could send a `GET` or `POST` request to your PHP script.

Example for getting the values from the bar chart (the key here is to look at the `onClick` function):

```js
var red, yellow, green, blue, grey, dept = "";

var c1 = document.getElementById('briskChart')
var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");
var briskChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Watch', 'Retired'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)',
        'rgba(255, 216, 0, 0.4)',
        'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4)',
        'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.4)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 216, 0, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(160, 160, 160, 1)'

      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]

  },
  options: {
    onClick: function(c, i) {
      element = i[0];  // the chart element you clicked on
      var xValue = this.data.labels[element._index];  // the x-value of the bar
      var yValue = this.data.datasets[0].data[element._index];  // the y-value of the bar
      console.log(xValue);
      console.log(yValue);
      // then, here, you could send a GET/POST request to your PHP function
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      fontSize: 24,
      text: dept + ' Dept Risk Summary',
      fontColor: '#000000'
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
          color: '#000000'
        },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "black",
          fontSize: 16
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
          color: '#000000'
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          fontColor: "black",
          fontSize: 16,
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="briskChart">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to play with it a bit.  My initial assumptions based on the console.log outputs is that I can assign a specific POST request for each data label returned?  e.g. if 5 is clicked, it invokes a 'document.five.submit' to execute a specific POST named five.  If 4 is clicked etc...

Comment: here's and example of the POST code I'm trying ... `if(xValue == 'Red'){document.bred.submit;}` not successful so far

Comment: Never mind ... got it working perfectly.  forgot to add '()' after the submit.  Thanks so much for the help.  This will be a great tool for me.